# Différence entre « vite » et « bientôt »

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Je voudrais savoir si ces deux mots sont échangeables ou s'ils ne le sont pas quand ils signifient "en relativement peu de temps".  Par exemple:

> Il est vite/bientôt revenu de son rendez-vous
>
> Il sera vite/bientôt guéri

Y a-t-il des différences en nuance?

Answer (score 6):

On ne peut pas les échanger dans la première phrase

« Il est vite revenu de son rendez-vous » implique que l'action est terminée alors que « Il est bientôt revenu de son rendez-vous », ou mieux, « Il sera bientôt revenu... », indique que le retour n'est pas encore effectif.

En revanche, au futur, les deux termes sont à peu près interchangeables mais le premier insiste sur le fait que la guérison est rapide alors que le deuxième indique qu'elle est proche.

Answer (score 0):

**Les deux sens sont différents, mais peuvent converger dans l'exemple fourni:**

vite = rapidement, en peu de temps. Cela s'applique au temps présent (ou au temps de la phrase).

bientôt = dans peu de temps. Cela concerne le futur.

**Différences:**

Il sera bientôt guéri (après dix ans de traitement) = très lentement (pas du tout vite).

Il sera vite guéri (quand nous aurons trouvé un remède, dans plusieurs années) = dans très longtemps (pas du tout bientôt).

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord avec les exemples donnés qui semblent en désaccord avec les définitions données juste au-dessus... Bientôt ne signifie pas "très lentement", et vite encore moins "dans très longtemps". Si l'on veut prendre l'exemple d'une guérison, "vite" et "bientôt" signifient tous deux qu'il n'y en a plus pour longtemps. Dans le cas d'un rhume, les deux conviendraient, dans le cas d'un cancer qui a duré plusieurs mois/années, "vite" paraîtrait un peu incongru.

Comment: @LaurentS. Les exemples n'étaient peut-être pas très bien expliqués, j'ai rajouté un commentaire entre parenthèses. Le but est de montrer que justement, le sens peut être totalement opposé. Une chose qui se termine bientôt après une longue période ne s'est pas déroulée vite.

Answer (score 0):

**Il est vite/bientôt revenu de son rendez-vous**.

**Il est vite revenu de son rendez-vous**=**passé composé**
Sens: **Il n'a pas tardé de revenir** de son rendez-vous.

**Il est bientôt revenu de son rendez-vous**=**présent historique pour vouloir dire et en forme écrite ou déclamée**:
Il sera bientôt revenu de son rendez-vous= un futur utiliser au présent.
Ce qui veut dire: dans peu de temps.

**Il sera vite guéri**=Il ne tardera pas à guérir, **sémantiquement la même chose que**=I**l sera bientôt guéri**